# Add 2D arrays side by side in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hello everyone I want to add 2 2x2 arrays side by side in python. In the end I want to get a 2x4 array which rows are shared and 1st and 2nd columns are from the first array and 3rd and the 4th columns are from the second array. I get an array where it sums the arrays not put them side by side. Can you help me please?

Example:

```
Array 1:
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]

Array 2:
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

Expected Result:

```
[[1 2 1 2]
 [1 2 1 2]]
```

Real Result:

```
[[2 4]
 [2 4]]

import numpy as np

a = np.matrix('1 2; 1 2')
b = np.matrix('1 2; 1 2')

x = a + b

print(x)
```

Comment: `np.matrix` is convenient for creating a small matrix with this string input, but generally we encourage creating arrays instead, from a nested list input:  `a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])`

Comment: I think @Thomas' answers make more sense than mine in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
>>> numpy.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
matrix([[1, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 2]])
```

Another option is using [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> np.hstack((a, b))
matrix([[1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` arrays do not act in the same way as python lists. Whereas the `+` operator can do some sort of list concatenation, when you use it with `numpy` arrays, you are doing vector addition.

Instead, you can flatten each array and concatenate:

```
np.concatenate([a.flatten(),b.flatten()])

matrix([[1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2]])
```

**[Edit:]**

re-reading your question, it seems I misunderstood what you were after. @Thomas' answers make more sense in your scenario, and an alternative would be [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> np.column_stack((a,b))
matrix([[1, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Can I use that for more than two arrays?

Comment: Yes, just put in all your desired arrays into the square brackets.

Comment: Why are you using `flatten` here?  I get a (1,8) for these 2 (2,2) matrices.

Comment: I think this solution works in this case because the matrices *on top* of each other are the same as they are *next* to each other.  I would recommend just `np.hstack((a, b))`, that's the numpythonic approach.

Comment: Yeah I guess from their expected results, I couldn't tell, I thought maybe they just wanted to flatten each array and concatenate them. It would have been more clear with different arrays, but I agree, the solutions in @Thomas' answer make more sense, and should be accepted.

Comment: Actually, `column_stack` might be more appropriate here, and since your answer is already accepted, might be worth adding the alternatives (I've rarely found askers to accept other answers).  Plus I think yours has more merit considering it explains why his attempt didn't work.

Comment: `column_stack` is only useful if the inputs are 1d; for 2d inputs `concatenate` is enough.  Look at their python code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I think why this is happening is because the addition returns a normal matrix addition that adds the two matrices component by component.

Try, np.concatenate(), it might help as @sacul has suggested.